# Best Buy - Products API problems

Tags: best-buy-api

I have a problem with BestBuy's Products API. I'm trying to search something like "samsung galaxy s3". I've tried with file_get_contents in my php page. My call is similar to: http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products((search=samsung&search=galaxy&search=s3)&salePrice>VALUE)?show=name,salePrice&format=xml&apiKey=MYAPIKEY;

This will return nothing. How can I search for phones?

Comment: I've tried also with name=rawurlencode(STRINGTOSEARCH), I miss categoryPath.id because I don't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complete you would like your answer. If you are looking for your Samsung Galaxy S III fulfilled by Best Buy use:
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name=%22Galaxy%20S%20III*%22&categoryPath.id=abcat0800000&categoryPath.id!=abcat0811002)?apiKey=YourAPIKey&show=sku,name,salePrice

If you would like to include Marketplace Samsung Galaxy S IIIs use:
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name=%22Galaxy%20S%20III*%22&categoryPath.id=abcat0800000&categoryPath.id!=abcat0811002&marketplace=*)?apiKey=YourAPIKey&show=sku,name,salePrice,marketplace&pageSize=100

For queries I searched the name field for Galaxy S III with a wildcard. I then filtered those results to be just cell phones. The second query opened up the search to also include Marketplace items.